# Use global variables inside static php class

Tags: php, global, static-classes

As I am new to php oop I have a question how do I use global variables inside a static class with out using the constructor? Or must I use in this case a constructor?

```
$varGlob = 'hello mars';

class statclass {

    global $varglob;

    protected static $newVar = $varglob;// not going to work

    static public function outputfunc(){
       return statClass::$newVar;
    }
}
```

Comment: [It's not OOP if you are resorting to globals and statics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527)

Answer (score 0):

As [`Gordon`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) mentioned you should not make use of `globals` or the thing I suggested because that will break your OOP design. You actually should pass the value through `constructor` [That's why they are meant for ]

However, the below code solves your purpose by making use of named constant such as [`define`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) , Sadly this is an ugly-way...

```
<?php
define("varGlob","hello");

class statclass
{
    protected static $newVar = varGlob;

    static public function outputfunc(){
        return statClass::$newVar;
    }
}

echo statclass::outputfunc(); //"prints" hello
```

### Alternate way.. (Recommended)

```
<?php

class settings
{
    # Populate all your variables that are to be used.
    protected $var1='Variable1';
    protected $var2='Variable2';
}

class yourclass extends settings
{
    # All those variables used in the class `settings` can be accessed here.
    public function disp()
    {
        echo $this->var1;
    }
}

$yc = new yourclass;
$yc->disp(); //"prints" Variable1
```

Comment: Okay that make sense, but I have a list of variables that I want to use inside several classes, so the best thing to do is to create a settings class and put the list of variables inside this class?

Comment: @user759235 Yes you could do that and make all the variables static.

Comment: @user759235, Yeah create a settings class and make those members(variables) `protected` and you can inherit this class and those variables will be available under your new class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use global variables in a PHP class, but static variables. Although this seems confusing, global's aren't meant to be used in object-oriented PHP, but rather 'normal' PHP, old style.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php for more information.